# lightSlider - Set active item in the middle of carousel

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

I'm using [lightSlider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/index.html) and I want to set as `active` the item always in the middle of carousel.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have added an option `centerSlide` which you can use to do just that. Here's a link to the commit that made the change -> https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/pull/227/commits/7d90ea7f0367d8c37036d24ada9041f206bed5d7

```
$("#lightSlider").lightSlider({
    ...
    centerSlide:true,    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code finds the item with "active" class and moves the slider to it.

```
var slider = $('#your-slider').lightSlider();    
slider.goToSlide($('.active').index());
```

Comment: Diego, lightslider set the active item in the first thumb. My goal is to have active item in the middle of slider always (without mind with its index or how much thumbs exist in the slider). Thanks anyway.